# The activity of being a roadie

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to reflect participating in the job of a roadie.  In the same way that you would describe activities as *selling*, *painting*, *driving*, is there such a word as roadieing? (I feel dirty typing it, so I suspect not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roadie?region=us) the word *roadie* acts as both noun and verb:

> *noun*
>
> a person employed by a touring band of musicians to set up and maintain equipment.
>
> *verb*
>   [no object]
>
> work as a roadie.

However, this seems a bit awkward ("I roadie for the Rolling Stones"), so you could also use the verb phrase *to be a roadie* or *to work as a roadie*. For example, it sounds natural to say:

> I worked as a roadie last summer.
>
> I was a roadie last summer.

Comment: Frustrating as it is, I think I will have to settle for a phrase rather than a single word.

Answer (score 4):

The activity of being a roadie is *touring*. I was with roadies myself and that's how they say it.

Comment: While this is correct, I doesn't work for my situation because it is not clear enough to someone who doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

So late to this conversation!

Both roadies and musicians can tour. Only roadies can roady. And when roadies work, they are roadying.

How do I know this? I roadied!

Comment: My missus was a roadie who roadied back in the 90s.  As I went to some of the gigs she was at, I suspect that we met whilst she was roadying but if I was at a concert, I was probably inebriated and oblivious to the roadies.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it spelled "roady" so the verb could probably be "roadying". Slightly better than "roadieing", but I don't think it's something I see written very often.